# How to Add textbox item to list in jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, list, textbox

I am new to jquery .I would like to have the functionality like.
User can Add custom text to Text Box and it will add to below List.
If user click remove that item then it also reomve from list.

I attached screenshot here.
Can any one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code for your need..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn_AddToList").click(function(){
    //alert($('input[name=List1]').val());  Its Let you know the textbox's value
    $('input[name=List1]').val().appendTo('#List2');
    });         
});
</script>
<input name="List1" type="text">
<input type="button" id="btn_AddToList" value="Add">
<select id="List2">
<option>---</option>
</select>
```

Its may helpful to you..

Thanks.

Comment: $(function()
{ $('#btn_AddToList').click(function()
    { var select = document.getElementById('lst_Regions');
        var region = $('#txt_RegionName').val();   
        if('' != region)
        { var newOption = document.createElement('option');

            newOption.text = region;
            newOption.value = region;
       
            if($.browser.msie){select.add(newOption);}
            else{select.add(newOption, null);}
        }
        return false;
    });  
 $("#btn_RemoveFromList").click(function() {
  $("#toListBox option:selected").appendTo("#fromListBox");
 }); 
});

Comment: <input type="text" name="region" id="txt_RegionName" /><br />
    <input type="button" name="add" id="btn_AddToList" value="add" /></br />
    <input type="button" name="remove" id="btn_RemoveFromList" value="remove" /></br />
    <select size="7" id="lst_Regions" style="width: 200px;">
    </select>

Comment: @Uresh Patel can you please use the formatting for your comments.

Comment: yes.Its bit a long for newbie in jquery i think..but good one..:)